# Wiring Arduino Mini Pro with CP2102 USB to TTL

Tags: arduino, usb, wiring, ttl

I have an Arduino Mini Pro and a CP2102 USB to TTL module as in the image below:

[image: My Arduino Mini Pro and CP2102 USB to TTL module]

I couldn't find a suitable guide for the module I have. So, **how should I wire them together?**

Answer (score 3):

```
Vcc -> Vcc (Make sure your arduino accepts 5V supply)
GND -> GND
TXD -> RXD
RXD -> TXD
```

Not much else to it, really.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I wire it, the led is getting on. The thing is that when I try to upload the sketch I'm getting ` stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00` (same as I didn't wired the arduino at all)

Comment: Be sure to transmit on the baudrate the device wants.

Comment: @Deepsy it's also important to connect DTR for [auto-reset to work](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/37740/13174). Without it, you would have to reset and time the upload manually which is tedious and error-prone. Also, there are different [Arduino Mino Pro voltage versions](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/28400/13174), so make sure to connect the Arduino VCC PIN to the right voltage (other USB2serial devices have a voltage switch/jumper).

Answer (score 1):

I have just bought myself a Arduino Pro Mini for a project and struggled with the wiring for the FDTI connection.  This is what worked for me:

Arduino     FDTI

```
GND -> GND
 -  -> CTS
VCC -> 5V 
RX1 -> TDX
TX0 -> RXD
DTR -> DRT
```

My Arduino also had a second GND pin on the header, which I didn't wire anywhere.

Hope this helps others with the same conenction issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's a video explaining how to wire them up right here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vawhrr4COjI

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because they become useless if the link dies (or video is removed in this case) so please add a summary of how it recommends connecting a CP2102.

Comment: It looks like Dzarda has it covered!

Answer (score 0):

Having tried many of the ideas here and elsewhere to resolve the "stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00" error eg. swapping Tx with Rx, holding the mini pro reset button until uploading of compiled sketch, etc. The thing that worked for me was to turn on verbose output and press the onboard reset button when the (orange) uploading text was shown - works every time for me.

Comment: If that worked this means that auto-reset didn't work, i.e. you also have to connect DTR for auto-reset to work.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work , one easy approach is to disconnect the RST header pin from CP2102 pin 9 and connect it to the RST pin (pin 24) instead. While in the Arduino schematics, the reset pin is connected to the ATmega328P pin 1 (RST) via a 100 ohm resistor, this connection is not strictly needed as pulses from the DTR pin (connected to ATmega328P pin 1 via a 100nF capacitor) will reset the MCU properly during programming.